How to hide a column based on a variable in Grafana
I have two columns 'IP Units' and 'SI Units' in my Grafana dashboard, I want to only show one of the columns based on a dashboard variable (think a string or boolean that I can hide or unhide the columns based off that).
Is there any way to do this? Perhaps through transformations?
I tried to see if there were any transformations available for this but could not find anything.

You can do that by filtering out unnecessary columns in your query using datasource means.
Another way is to use Grafana's Filter fields by name transformation:

